# AWS Glue Databrew, manipulating data with code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-databrew

In Glue Databrew, there is a part that you can manipulate data with recipes. It has some conditions. You can prepare the data without coding. For example you can say "if City Column's value is 'New York', make it 'NY'" with the key condition words that the recipe part has. But I want to manipulate the data with code. Can I do that in Databrew? For example, I'd like to manipulate it with python.